# Null check operator used on a null value on safe area

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

help me, I'm still stuck here for the past few days. why is it like this? error indicates there is an error in "dashboard_bottom_nav"
[image: error]

and when I try to click the error it directs me to this class and directs it to SafeArea
[image]

I really need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code may be it will help you because your error is clear it saying null check should be apply on nullable object.

```
    // you can apply null handling on that line where it showing error
    var title = text;
    if (title != null) {
        var len = title.length; // Safe
    }


    //or use default null safety operator
    Use ?. and ??
    
    var len = title?.length ?? 0; // Provide a default value if title is null.
```